# Response.RedirectToRoute not working with MVC areas when routing from ASPX code behind file

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http

I have an aspx code behind file that has method that is trying to redirect to an MVC route in the same project. The MVC and Webforms live side by side in the same web project and I have no problems there, but when I try to redirect to an MVC area/controller/action from an ASPX page code behind it cant find the area im looking for. It throws an error that is using the wrong area.

In my case I have a Utilities area and its trying to use that instead of the one I want. Does anyone know why this would be failing like that? Even though I specified the area in the route parameters?

Heres an example of what im trying to do.

```
Response.RedirectToRoute(new
    {
        area = "Billing",
        controller = "BhpReport",
        action = "CreateReport",
        startDate,
        salesLocation
    });
```

But I end up with this error

```
The controller for path '/Utilities/BhpReport/CreateReport' was not found or does not implement IController.
```

As you can see, im not trying to go to Utilities im trying to go to Billing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring out how to use the RedirectToRoute method correctly.

```
Response.RedirectToRoute("Billing", new
    {
        controller = "BhpReport", 
        action = "CreateReport", 
        startDate, 
        salesLocation
    });
```

This was the solution, I needed to separate out the area into a "route" variable, then add a new object for route values.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to access Utilities anywhere else in the code? Doesn't seem like the code you have posted would impose that error.

Also Reponse.Redirect excepts a string or string and a bool as parameters. So try:

```
Response.Redirect("/BhpReport/CreateReport")
```

or

```
return RedirectToAction("CreateReport", "BhpReport")
```

---

**Update**

If the purpose is to send startDate and salesLocation to the CreateReport action, you could try:

```
return RedirectToAction("CreateReport", "BhpReport", new { sd = startDate, sl = salesLocation })
```

And in the CreateReport action you do:

```
    public ActionResult CreateReport(string startDate, string salesLocation) {
    // do stuff 
    }
```

Comment: No im not trying to access it anywhere else, and I did switch to using the Response.Redirect and it worked fine. I would rather use the other way so I can define the arguments more clearly as an object than just a string but I cant figure out how to get around that error im having. It must have something to do with the way the areas are being registered or something, because Utilities is the last area, so its like its just defaulting to the last one registered then erroring out.